# How to mention the empty password rainbow table lookup trick to extract the SALT using Python?

Tags: python, django, salt

I am setting the static salt value to hash the password using Python. I am providing my code below.

settings.py:

```
SALT = "2Y7xk5vrs5DeCcSdinRVKQ=="
```

views.py:

```
import hashlib
from django.conf import settings
def signsave(request):
    """This function helps to save signup data"""

    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('uname')
        password = request.POST.get('pass')
        con_pass = request.POST.get('conpass')
        if password == con_pass:
            salt = settings.SALT
            hashed_password = hashlib.sha512(password + salt).hexdigest()
            passw = User(
                uname=name,
                password=hashed_password
            )
            passw.save()
            message = "Registered successfully"
            return render(request, 'bookingservice/login.html',
                        {'msg': message})
        else:
            message = "The password did not match "
            return render(request, 'bookingservice/signup.html',
                        {'msg': message})
```

Here I am defining the static value for salt but here also I need the empty password rainbow table lookup trick to extract the SALT.

Comment: Why can't you use the Django builtin User.check_password ?

Comment: Are you using the supplied Django auth User model?  That takes care of password hashing for you from my understanding.  No need to salt and hash them yourself.

Comment: @Kyle : Actually I am working on vulnerabilities so I have to make like this or testing.

Comment: `'bookingservice/signup.html'` is your reference point, need some `javascript`action for add new `hidden input` to form, after `if your_private_keys in your_post_keys` process `passwd`. So session isn't only `login`, `visit` already a session !

Comment: @dsgdfg : Did not get you. Can you please elaborate it by one post ?

Comment: Your question is `how to know user is valid and all form inputs filled correctly`, No way ! This information stay on visitor side, but on visitor side create `Read Only` variables(hidden input), check password inputs length or send to server `username` first and give him a `secret token` etc.

Comment: What in the world are you talking about? Rainbow tables are tools for cracking password hashes to discover the original password. No normal web application needs to find the original password. What is your actual goal?